# How to set as external all node modules in rollup?

Tags: node.js, module, rollup

I want to have all modules imported from node_modules as external.
What is the configuration for this?

I tried without success :

```
import path from "path";
import glob from "glob";
import multiEntry from "rollup-plugin-multi-entry";

export default {
    entry: "src/**/*.js",
    format: "cjs",
    plugins: [
        multiEntry()
    ],
    external: glob.sync("node_modules/**/*.js").map(file => path.resolve(file)),
    dest: "dist/bundle.js"
}];
```

or

```
import multiEntry from "rollup-plugin-multi-entry";

export default {
    entry: "src/**/*.js",
    format: "cjs",
    plugins: [
        multiEntry()
    ],
    external: id => id.indexOf("node_modules") !== -1,
    dest: "dist/bundle.js"
}];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can accomplish that using package.json dependencies field:

```
const pkg = require('./package.json');

export default {
    // ...
    external : Object.keys(pkg.dependencies),
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Interesting trick! But it doesn't include node built-in modules like `fs` and `path`. So I forced to use: `external: [...Object.keys(pkg.dependencies), 'fs', 'path']` in my personal project.

Comment: This is not a complete answer as it doesn't handle transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 13):

Using rollup 2.63 this works for me

```
export default {
    // ...
    external: [/node_modules/],
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and ensures all dependencies are excluded, including transitive ones.

Comment: Note that for this to work you need to use the [node-resolve](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/node-resolve) plugin, [as pointed out in the doc](https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#external).

Comment: Also if you have symlinked dependencies (which might be the case if, say, you have a monorepo), you will need to add [`preserveSymlinks: true`](https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#preservesymlinks) for those to be properly considered as "external".

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE:

Use [rollup-plugin-auto-external](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-auto-external).

---

Thank [@IsidroTorregrosa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8583739/isidro-torregrosa) for [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46144545/5318303) (and [@maxkueng](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-node-resolve/issues/77#issuecomment-297992040) ofcourse). I improved it by adding node built-in modules (like `fs` and `path`) and also `peerDependencies`. Use:

```
import builtins from 'builtin-modules/static'
const pkg = require('./package.json')
// ...
export default {
    external: builtins.concat(Object.keys(pkg.dependencies || {})).concat(Object.keys(pkg.peerDependencies || {})),
    // ...
}
```

---

See [builtin-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/builtin-modules) on *npmjs.com* and also see:

https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-node-resolve#resolving-built-ins-like-fs

Comment: FYI newcomers: At the time I'm writing this comment, `rollup-plugin-auto-external` appears to be unmaintained and did not work with Rollup v3 in my (limited) testing.

Comment: For those interested: There is also [`rollup-plugin-node-externals`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-node-externals), which appears to be maintained and customizable. Though, my frontend/js/node knowledge won't be able to tell if necessary or not.

Answer (score 1):

###### Rollup Configuration

```js
import pkg from "./package.json";

/**
 * Rollup bundler configuration.
 *
 * @see https://rollupjs.org/
 * @type {import("rollup").RollupOptions}
 */
export default {
  ...
  external: [...Object.keys(pkg.dependencies), /^node:/]
}
```

###### Application Source Code

```js
import path from "node:path";
import fs from "node:fs/promises";

...
```

Source: [GraphQL API and Relay Starter Kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/relay-starter-kit) → [`api/rollup.config.js`](https://github.com/kriasoft/relay-starter-kit/blob/82a71757e2990ebb10c922228f34c2f993c966df/api/rollup.config.js#L135-L138)

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me

```
external: id => !(path.isAbsolute(id) || id.startsWith("."));
```

Source: https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-node-resolve/issues/110#issuecomment-350353632